# Use terraform to set up a glue workflow triggered by the completion of a lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-glue, aws-event-bridge

I would like to run an AWS Glue Workflow when a lambda functions finishes executing. From what I read, it should be possible to do. But, I haven't found any examples on how to do this. Could someone show me how to do this via terraform?